# Lists vs dataframes

Tags: r

I am finding it very difficult to work with list e.g. 5 lists and each list has multiple elements.

- Conditionally remove the element (for dataframe, I could use subset function)
- Add new elements into an existing list (for dataframe I could use `rbind` to add new row into dataframe). I read that it is bad practice from memory efficiency to re-define list and keep adding new element by loop.
- Update particular element of existing List (for dataframe, I could use `df$col1 <- "new value"`)

Is there any performance issue if we mostly use data frame? OR is it bad programming practice ? We can always fetch a dataframe's column as a list using the `apply` family of functions.

Comment: I think using dataframe is the good practice instead of using nested lists in r. R has the data type tibble based on dataframe, using that instead of nested list will have benefits.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, a fresh installation of *R* doesn't have a "tibble" data type. That is a special object type from the "tibble" package, a user-contributed package, which has to be installed and loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! Use data frames if you can. If your data is rectangular, absolutely use a data frame. You can also use data frames with list columns, for the best of both worlds.

To your specific points:

> Conditionally remove the element (for dataframe, I could use subset function)

`Filter` is probably the closest thing to this for lists, removing items based on a condition. You can also use `[` if you want to remove elements by name or index.

> Add new elements into an existing list (for dataframe I could use rbind to add new row into dataframe). I read that it is bad practice from memory efficiency to re-define list and keep adding new element by loop.

You can use `c()` to add new elements to lists. You're right, it is bad practice to re-define list and add new elements in a loop. It is also bad practice to redefine data frames and add new elements in a loop with `rbind` (perhaps even worse than it is for lists).

> Update particular element of existing List (for dataframe, I could use `df$col1 <- "new value"`)

That exact syntax will work for lists too.

```
my_list <- list(a = 1:3, b = 11:13)
my_list$b <- "hi"
```

---

If you use lists frequently, you may want to look at the `purrr` package. It contains many nice functions for working with lists.